# need help with vbscript "oShell.run" command

Tags: vbscript

When I execute the following code it works, but I need to wait for the code to complete; before I can execute the rest of my program. How do I do this?

Works, but doesn't wait:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
oShell.Run "sftp2.exe -B " & strOutputFile
```

Doesn't Work:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Return =  oShell.Run ("sftp2.exe -B " & strOutputFile, 1, true)
```

Works, but doesn't wait:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set oExec = oShell.Exec ("sftp2.exe -B " & strOutputFile)
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, are you getting an error message of any kind?  It sounds as though sftp2.exe is not executing (or returning an immediate error) or that it does not issue a return code when it exits.  You might try doing this with WMI instead when you can actually watch its process.

Answer (score 1):

In your third example, you can poll the [`WshScriptExec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2f38xsxe%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object's status until the process has completed:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set oExec = oShell.Exec ("sftp2.exe -B " & strOutputFile)

Do While oExec.Status = 0
     WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

' as you were...
```

although your examples look much like they're taken from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) so I'm not sure why they don't work. Perhaps it's the way your program `sftp2.exe` operates which is causing the issue? If it's anything like the usual `ftp` application, it will run as a kind-of command prompt which may not be compatible. I'm just speculating.

Comment: Thanks for the response.    I was thinking about the loop with the sleep, but it seems any command that I execute after "Set oExec = oShell.Exec ("sftp2.exe -B " & strOutputFile)" seems to cause the sftp not to complete properly. I also noticed that "oShell.Run ("sftp2.exe -B " & strOutputFile, 1, true)" fails because I am not in the correct directory for the files. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks again for the help. I figured out why it was not working properly. Absolute path vs relative path. I was using relative path and this was causing the below code to fail, since it wasn't sure were to find the files to sftp. To my suprize absolute path is not necessary in the other two examples above that worked.

This works with absolute path (ie. put `"C:\somefolder\file";` a command in my `"strOutputFile"` file).

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

Return =  oShell.Run ("sftp2.exe -B " & strOutputFile, 1, true)
```